# Would a city carved into a side of a ravine be plausible?

Tags: society

A small city, barely even one, that built everything at the side of cliffs to be protected from the strong winds above.

Is something like it plausible? I can't seem to find examples of it outside of fantasy.

Comment: Yes actually, there were a few examples of cities entirely made by carving Rock formations

Comment: If people have way to get water and food supply in that ravine it's definitely plausible.

Comment: One thing that often prevents these cities is the stability of the cliff above. Because if the stone is regularily dropping bricks on people's heads nobody will want to live there. Since such rocks are somewhat rare, so are these cities. I'm not a geologist but I'm pretty sure that its like a specific type of rock that really allows for this

Comment: This was certainly a thing among natives in the desert part of North America.  You can still see some of these ruins in Arizona, for example.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there actually are a few examples, the topmost I remember are:

- [***Matera, Italy***](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/matera-italy/index.html): a city carved directly into the rock
- [***Derinkuyu Underground city, Turkey***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derinkuyu_underground_city) completely underground multi-level city carved into the rock

Comment: I think that Derinkuyu is the best example for really dug into the ground.

Answer (score 34):

The **Anasazi cliff dwellings** are the best New World ones.

[image: cliff dwellings]

https://www.pbslearningmedia.org/resource/social-studies-142-mg-r1-grades-6-12/anasazi-cliff-dwellings-at-mesa-verde-national-park/

**Petra** is a cool old world one.

[image: petra]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCoyRrylVrg

This is good in that it shows you a lot of the different buildings carved into the rock.  I love those stairs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCoyRrylVrg

Comment: As far as I know the cliff-buildings at Petra are only tombs and temples. The actual houses were normal buildings. So calling Petra a city build into a cliff is maybe a bit of a stretch.

Comment: [Mesa Verde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_Verde_National_Park) is a sight to behold, +1

Comment: @Tonny Many houses in Petra were carved inside smaller rocks. A few are still inhabited.

Comment: @dargaud It isn't really mentioned in any online sources that I can quickly find. I asked my parents (who visited the place some 25 years ago) and they don't recall either. But you could be right.

Comment: There are many other cliff dwellings in southwestern US.  Homes and food storage are a part of each.

Comment: @Tonny I visited 7 years ago and took pictures. Some big boulders have rooms carved inside, with doors and windows and families sitting up front selling some wares. And some (non-vertical) slopes as well, carved into 'apartment layers', with terraces. But it's mostly uninhabitated now.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed by other answers, there are much known examples, sometimes even huge ones. There are actually a lot of them all over the world, but I just wanted to add an example that perfectly fits your description and which I visited, Roque Saint-Cristophe. At the time of its destruction it was "A small city, barely even one", really well protected at the side of the cliff.

Reproduction of how the city was at its destruction (source: http://envievoyages.blogspot.com):

[image: reproduction of how the city was at its destruction]

To give a better idea of the scale: (source: Oups79 — Travail personnel, CC BY-SA 1.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1102461)

[image]

It's been inhabited from prehistoric times to 1588 (when the king besieged and totally annihilated the city which completely filled the natural cave in the cliff)

The [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roque_Saint-Christophe) is only a stub, you'll find more pictures in the [French one](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roque_Saint-Christophe)

Answer (score 2):

A ravine implies that it was created by erosion, do you mean a cliff? Strong winds would likely bring weather of some kind, depending on the climate in your area/world. The Anasazi and Petra are great examples, but note that they are in arid climates where you don't have to worry about rain eroding your foundations and washing your city away. Other considerations: density/hardness of rock (are your settlers using natural crevices or do they need to carve into the surface to make new rooms/buildings?), light (as windows would only be on the exterior walls, any buildings would likely only be one room deep unless you're building storage/cellar-type rooms).

Answer (score 2):

For another example, this is [Vardzia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vardzia), in [Georgia](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vardzia/@41.3822287,43.2849392,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xa3f04b72bcb61f1c!8m2!3d41.3810511!4d43.284247):

[image: From down below]

[image: From the inside 1]

[image]